# Excel Min/Max Query for Golf Handicap spreadsheet

Tags: excel

Good Afternoon All

Its been a long time since I've used Excel and have become stuck and I hope you can help

Column O3 = 3

Column P3 = 4

Column Q3 = =IF(P3<=O3,MAX(0),IF(P3>=O3,MIN(2),IF(P2=O2+1,MAX(1))))

If PAR = 3 (O3) then if I score 3 or less (P3) I want to show 0 (Q3), if I score 4 I want Q3 to show 1 (Q3), If i score 5 or above I want to show 2 (Q3)

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: Wayne, can you detail what you expected with this macro ? Your last IF condition test P2 and O2, it is necessary ? Your last IF condition, has no third parameter, a miss ?

Comment: Hi palmplam

If PAR = 3 (O3) then if I score 3 or less (P3) I want to show 0 (Q3), if I score 4 I want Q3 to show 1 (Q3), If i score 5 or above I want to show 2 (Q3)

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: In the "Formulas" menu, there's a feature "Evaluate Formula". This executes your formula bit by bit, which allows you to see when exactly you don't get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Dominique, its seems I have too many trues on my formula. :-) So I need to rethink the whole formula. Any ideas where i should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wyane,

I think your macro must be like this :

```
=IF(P3<=O3,0,IF(P3=(O3+1),1,2))
```

If P3 <= O3 = 0

If P3 = O3+1 = 1

Else 2 (score 5 and above)